# Killing long running multiple sessions for oracle db using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, ksh

I am working on shell script, on when a statement is identified as long running, we have to get PID on OS, Make sure its not the main process of the Program.(ex: Oracle). Check top and kill the matching process and later we can check the database using script for long running sessions if any still exist. After killing the particular long running PID of the program, shell script needs to send out mail information to the user.

```
[oracle@jumbox ]$ps au |grep oracle | awk 'print {$2}' |uniq
10020
15678
17345
18736
18856
```

My question here is i dont see any of the above process listed in top command, so how should i validate these non existing processes within the script? or is there any better one liner or code snippet which can do the trick ? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the documentation for `SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT`, maybe it can help you. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF227

Answer (score 0):

Killing a session from server is very risky and it could lead to ambiguous data and even unreadable rows in the table. Its better to kill long running sessions by checking the same in `v$session` view. Here you can check if the session is inactive or waiting for another session to complete.

To kill a session use `alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' immediate;`, where sid and serial# can be found in `v$session` view. To get the server PID of a session you can query `v$process` and `v$session` views with this query:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, s.username, p.spid, s.machine, p.terminal
FROM v$session s, v$process p
WHERE s.paddr = p.addr;
```

Comment: Hi Lohit,
Thanks for your suggestion, but can we atleast check out to compare the processes or SPID's listed above with top processess prevailing and then can we validate ? Before killing from oracle I just need to validate that if its NOT the main oracle process that we are killing..also Oracle process is just an example, we have many other executables to compare..!! any suggestions on it are much appreciated..!! Thanks.

Comment: To do that, you can take the SPIDs you get from `top` and check what is getting executed in those processes, as most of the time idle processes will not be displayed in the top CPU consuming processes. To check what is getting executed in an oracle process, you can check out [this](http://www.acehints.com/2014/06/oracle-query-to-find-out-sql-text-using.html) link.